# Confused over DLL entry points (entry point not found exception)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm trying to learn how to use DLL's in C#.  I have a very simple DLL just to test the basics.

```
// MainForm.cs


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DLL_Test
{
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            [DllImport("TestDLL.dll",
                        EntryPoint="?Add@@YGHHH@Z",
                        ExactSpelling = true,
                        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
            public static extern int Add(int a, int b);

            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                int num;
                try
                {
                    num = Add(2, 3);
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(num.ToString() + "\n");
                }
                catch (DllNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
                catch (EntryPointNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
             }
         }
}
```

And the DLL code:

```
// TestDLL.cpp

__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall Add(int a, int b) {
return(a + b);
}
```

dumpbin returns the following:

```
ordinal   hint   RVA        name
      1      0   00011005   ?Add@@YGHHH@Z = @ILT+0(?Add@@YGHHH@Z)
```

This (and other attempts listed below) have all returned the same exception:

```
System.EntryPointException: Unable to find entry point named "..."
```

So I am at a loss for how to solve this.  Perhaps I do not understand how DllMain functions as the C# entry point for a DLL.  TestDLL.dll works when I test it in a C++ application.

After searching for help, I've attempted the following changes:

```
// TestDLL.cpp

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall Add(int a, int b) {
return(a + b);
}
```

Which results in this from dumpbin

```
ordinal   hint   RVA        name
      1      0   00011005   _Add@8 = @ILT+135(_Add@8)
```

Thus, I changed my C# code:

```
 // MainForm.cs

...

[DllImport("TestDLL.dll",
                        EntryPoint="_Add",
                        ExactSpelling = true,
                        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
            public static extern int Add(int a, int b);

...
```

I've also tried `__cdecl`:

```
// TestDLL.cpp

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl Add(int a, int b) {
return(a + b);
}
```

.

```
// MainForm.cs

...

[DllImport("TestDLL.dll",
                        EntryPoint="_Add",
                        ExactSpelling = true,
                        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
            public static extern int Add(int a, int b);

...
```

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the calling conventions.  Any help would be very appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Is that message accurate?  Seeing "..." as the function name that can't be found is *very* strange.

Comment: @GregD I had an issue with DllImport and it was a miss match on the method name. In my case I was calling "Mouse_event" instead of "mouse_event". Since I was getting the "entry point not found" and it can lead to several different opinions it took me a while to solve. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall Add(int a, int b) { ... }
```

and

```
[DllImport("TestDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Stdcall)] 
public static extern int Add(int a, int b);
```

`extern "C"` will prevent name mangling with params and return type such as `?Add@@YGHHH@Z`.
__stdcall will prepend an `_` and add `@8` : `_Add@8` (where 8 is the total size of arguments). Note that it also affects the way parameters are pushed on the stack.

In your `DLLImport` statement, since you specify `CallingConvention.StdCall`, you don't need to specify the name mangling. Just give the regular name (`Add`) and .NET will take care of name mangling (`_Add@8`).

Note that you **must** specify the CallingConvention or .NET wouldn't emit the correct code to push arguments on the stack

Comment: Thank you for your response, but no dice.  I implemented the exact code above and still receive the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

Unmanged:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Add(int a, int b) 
{
    return(a + b);
}
```

Managed:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("TestDLL.dll")]
    public static extern int Add(int a, int b);

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Add(1, 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've attempted these exact commands as well in both Console and Window applications.  Could my project settings require a change?

Comment: @Darin : Nope, calling convention mismatch. C++ is `__cdecl` by default, .Net expects `__stdcall` by default.

Comment: @GregD, ildjarn, I have just tested this code and it worked perfectly fine. It is true though that in my example there is a mismatch between the .NET and C++ calling conventions.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I had a similar problem, solved creating an EMPTY C++ dll project. Probably the standard Visual Studio template causes some trouble.

Refer to this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9826/How-to-create-a-DLL-library-in-C-and-then-use-it-w