# Why do I always get a "System.EntryPointNotFoundException" in mscor.lib?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

If I create a new, empty WPF project and build and run it, everything works as expected and the applications exits with code 0, but in the debug output I always see a message:

`Exception thrown: 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' in mscorelib.dll`

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new project in visual studio using the "Visual C# / Windows / WPF Application" template
2. Hit 'Start'

Is this normal? And how do I get rid of it?

Thanks,
  Michael

**Update:** Full debug window output

```
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. 
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Michael\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SDEars\SDEars\bin\Release\SDEars.vshost.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x19a8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x22ec has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'c:\users\michael\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SDEars\SDEars\bin\Release\SDEars.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Accessibility\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Accessibility.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown: 'System.EntryPointNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.Aero\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.Aero.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp\VisualStudio.XamlDiagnostics.9068\WpfXamlDiagnosticsTap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop\7.1.40304.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationProvider\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationProvider.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'SDEars.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SDEars.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-SystemData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemData.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[9068] SDEars.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

**Update 2:** Would appreciate any pointers on how to start debugging this

Comment: It is not normal. It looks like CLR cannot find your Main method. That's weird.

Comment: Typically it just say "Loaded ..." bunch of times, my guess one of such references isn't valid (then you get [missing entry point for dll](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7276389/1997232)). Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/564681/1997232). Have you tried to searching for exception? Can you post exact content of Output window?

Comment: Searching for the exception wasn't very helpful: It's all about people trying to load DLLs, and I'm not! Also no "first chance exception" messages. Have added debug output now. Thanks!

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2015, Version 14.0.25425.01 Update 3

Comment: Run it in WinDbg, `sxe clr` to break on CLR first chance exceptions.

Comment: It seems that your application does not do much. Can you provide it for download?

Comment: System.Configuration appears to be involved, you need to take any exceptions thrown by that assembly with a bolder of salt.  It uses XML serialization and it has a habit of [randomly trying to load assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3798614/17034).  Try using Fuslogvw.exe to find the file.  Otherwise just ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone!
It went away after loading a bunch of (overdue) windows updates. Still no idea what was going wrong, but 'fixed' now...