# vb.net dll entry points to allow registration (for use on Excel)

Tags: vb.net, dll, dllimport

I've created a DLL file using VB.NET on my home computer (code example below). I've made it COM-visible, registered for COM interop, I can build this and transfer the .dll to my system32 folder, reference it in Excel and it works great.

The problem I have now is how to deploy this on multiple computers? I figure I'm trying to register it on a new computer (since visual studio does this bit for me on my PC). When trying to register the DLL regsvr32, it tells me there's no entry point. When I try using RegAsm, it says it's unable to locate input assembly. HOW can I create a stand alone dll that can be dropped in to system 32 and then registered on other computers (using VB.NET class library)?

I've seen quite a few pages regarding DLLs with C++ and my C++ skills are basic, I can't seem to pick out any lines to do with entry points or if I even have the right idea. Is an entry point a line or two of code inside a class or the dll or for each function or what?! I've visited about 40 different pages which either give me easy level, what I've already done or seem way above my technical understanding.

I originally started to group all my Excel modules together for easy distribution but now I've got hooked on this DLL idea I can't stop until I understand it and get it working! Please help!

Closest answer I can get (again in C++) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276389/confused-over-dll-entry-points-entry-point-not-found-exception) and I believe I need some sort of command line called DLLMain or DLLImport or something :s

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Namespace fooBAR

    <Guid("1C940E48-916E-4573-8ED2-B67112B5DDB2")>
    <ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)>
    Public Class cls_myStackOverflowExample

        Public searchTerm As String
        Public Function checkFormat() As Boolean
            If Len(searchTerm) = 10 Then
                checkFormat = True
            Else
                checkFormat = False
            End If
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Using RegAsm.exe is required.  You are doing it wrong, we can't see you doing it wrong.

Comment: OK so I can ignore regsvr32. Now, with the .dll moved in to system32, I tried various combos of RegAsm.exe from the cmd prompt. I tried specifying the full path, just the .dll name, with and without /codebase, from the .net v2.x and v4.x and also from both Framework and Framework64. On this PC and the 2nd PC. Every attempt says it's Unable to locate input assembly or one of its dependencies. What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?!

Comment: I've also tried placing the .dll in the SysWOW64 file since I read this worked for someone who moved to a 64-bit OS (which is what I'm on)

Comment: The solve AS ALWAYS was simple. I had to run cmd as administrator.

Comment: Don't put files in the system directories.

Comment: Where do I put them? How can I get them to register as part of a package? This whole topic has left me depressed.